# LG L90 doesn't install debug usb drivers

Tags: android, eclipse, driver

I have a problem with the driver for a LG L90. The ADT (for Eclipse) doesn't see the smartphone. The problem is that the phone isn't able to install the drivers.
Does anyone have any idea how I can do? The drivers, that I tried to install, are those of the official website.

Comment: Install the LG-PC-suite. I had this issue with Samsung devices. Installing Kies worked for me. Hope its the same for LG

Comment: time ago i used this http://adbdriver.com/downloads/ maybe could help you?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How to Enable USB Debugging for LG Optimus (LGD415). Android version 4.4.2 (KitKat)
Go to this website and download the drivers to your phone:
http://www.lg.com/us/support/mobile-support
For example, mine would be:
http://www.lg.com/us/support-mobile/lg-LGD415RD. Then click on “Software Update & Drivers”

On your phone, you need to enable USB debugging. To do so,
Go to “Settings”.
Go to “About Phone”
Go to “Software Information”
Tap “Build number” five times.
A pop-up will appear saying “You are now a developer”. Your’re not done yet.

Go back to your phone’s home page by pushing the home button.
Go to “Settings”.
Go to “Developer options”
Click the “USB debugging- Turn on debug mode when USB is connected”. A blue checkmark will appear.

Unplug your phone from your PC. Then plug it back in. On the pop-up, make sure you set it to “Media Sync (MTP)”.

Now your phone will show up on an option when you want to run your app in Eclipse.

Comment: +1, This even worked with Visual Studio for a Xamarin.Android project! Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

With LG L90 it might help to do the following steps:

- activate developer tools and mark USB debugging
- USB-connect via MTP
- activate teathering/networks > USB-teathering (after connecting, each time again)

Using the latest LG software-update Android 5.01 i was able to connect to a desktop chrome on Windows and Mac.

Answer (score -1):

- Go to **Settings**.
- Go to **About Phone**.
- Tap **Developer Options** until it says "you are now a Developer" and
  then back out of the screen and you will see Developer options